# PHP XPath queries: how to understand them?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, xpath-2.0

I'm new to PHP and I just realized that **XPath queries are NOT written in PHP**... is that right and eventually what language should I study to master them ?
XML? Javascript?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Comment: This page from msdn helped me a lot : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath is its own language.  This is a decent tutorial to get you started: http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html

Perhaps where your confusion comes in is that because XPath is one of the easiest ways of querying XML, many other languages have functions and methods that allow them to use it.  As you may have discovered, PHP has Xpath related classes in both its [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) libraries.

Comment: With _"PHP has Xpath related classes in both its DOM and SimpleXML libraries"_ did you mean: both DOM (parse potentially broken html) and SimpeXML (parse valid XML files) has classes that support XPath usage? Sorry for my buggy explanation but I'm really new to all this

Comment: yep. DOM has DOMXPath (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and SimpleXML has SimpleXMLElement::xpath (http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)